# SQL Data Query Error: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'join'

Tags: sql

I'm trying to develop a query: 
https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new

Maybe you guys could help:

1. Given a user's current popular tags, I want to find similar questions which:
2. Have the highest view counts (i.e. greater than 500) but which also have
3. Less than 20 answers.
4. Ordered by View Count

There is an error occuring somewhere in the second paragraph, somewhere near the join query here: `join #tags t on t.TagId = TagId`, saying: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'join'.

Assistance much appreciated:

```
        DECLARE @UserId int = ##UserId##

        create table #tags (TagId int, [Count] int)
        insert #tags 
        SELECT TOP 20 
        TagId,
        COUNT(*) AS UpVotes 
        FROM Tags
          INNER JOIN PostTags ON PostTags.TagId = Tags.id
          INNER JOIN Posts ON Posts.ParentId = PostTags.PostId
          INNER JOIN Votes ON Votes.PostId = Posts.Id and VoteTypeId = 2
        WHERE 
          Posts.OwnerUserId = @UserId
        GROUP BY TagId
        ORDER BY UpVotes DESC  

        select top 2000 [Post Link], Views
        join #tags t on t.TagId = TagId  
        where
          ViewCount > 500 and AnswerCount < 20
        order by ViewCount desc
```

### Update

```
DECLARE @UserId int = ##UserId##

    create table #tags (TagId int, [Count] int)
    insert #tags 
    SELECT TOP 20 
    TagId,
    COUNT(*) AS UpVotes 
    FROM Tags
      INNER JOIN PostTags ON PostTags.TagId = Tags.id
      INNER JOIN Posts ON Posts.ParentId = PostTags.PostId
      INNER JOIN Votes ON Votes.PostId = Posts.Id and VoteTypeId = 2
    WHERE 
      Posts.OwnerUserId = @UserId
    GROUP BY TagId
    ORDER BY UpVotes DESC  

    select top 2000 [Post Link], Views
    from Posts
    join #tags t on t.TagId = posts.TagId  
    where
      posts.ViewCount > 500 and posts.AnswerCount < 20
      order by posts.ViewCount desc
```

but the Posts table has a tags column: nvarchar (250). How can I match for that?

Comment: Whats TagId on which join is happening?

Comment: @Gauravsa TagId to be on the current Table being operated on: i.e. on all Posts - the posts table

Answer (score 2):

I think you missed the "FROM" statement before making the join

Answer (score 1):

Table variables are batch scoped variables try this (t1 is a variable from another temp table, have simply used t1 from temp as an example).

```
select top 2000 [Post Link], Views
        join #tags t, #tags t1 on t.TagId = t1.TagId  
        where
          t.ViewCount > 500 and t.AnswerCount < 20
        order by t.ViewCount desc
```